# Написать функцию на C# для программы на C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, интеграция

У меня есть проект на С++, в котором мне надо делать выборки из WMI. Через C# это гораздо легче, поэтому хотел бы сделать с помощью него. По сути передавать мне надо будет строки, в которых будет имя компьютера, namespace, класс и название полей (3 - 4 на каждый класс), а возвращать контейнер пар типа <название поля, значение>. Как лучше всего это сделать, можно ли написать библиотеку на C# и использовать её в С++? Использовать C++/CLI вряд ли получится, слишком много переписывать придётся.

Comment: Такое возможно: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=44349 (для C# module превращается в static class), для передачи строк, скорее всего понадобится передавать указатель на char с использованием unsafe-кода на шарпе, либо bstr с MarshalAs (не проверял ни один вариант). Но я бы рекомендовал подумать о написании dll на c++/cli.

Comment: А по моему это изврат. Во первых, WMI берет информацию либо из реестра, либо из firmware-таблиц, с которыми без проблем можно работать из си. Смысл навешивать на абстракцию еще один уровень абстракции. Во-вторых, можно просто парсить вывод wmic, если на то пошло.

Comment: @VadimTagil: Работать на уровне WinAPI — достаточно сложная задача. Ручное управление памятью и проверка кодов ошибок — несложные, но достаточно нудные занятия, требующие повышенного внимания и сосредоточенности. Интерфейс к WMI на C# намного приятнее.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, проще всего написать код на C#, и мелкую обёртку на C++/CLI.

Пример. Пусть у вас есть код на C#

```
public class QueryLibrary
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> RunQuery(string machineName, string className) { ... }
}
```

Вы создаёте обёртку на C++/CLI:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace msclr::interop;

std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> RunQuery(
    const std::wstring& machineName,
    const std::wstring& className)
{
    QueryLibrary^ ql = gcnew QueryLibrary();
    String^ machineNameMng = marshal_as<String^>(machineName);
    String^ classNameMng = marshal_as<String^>(className);
    Dictionary<String^, String^>^ result = ql->RunQuery(machineNameMng, classNameMng);
    std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> resultMap;
    for each (KeyValuePair<String^, String^>^ kvp in result)
    {
        std::wstring key = marshal_as<std::wstring>(kvp->Key);
        std::wstring value = marshal_as<std::wstring>(kvp->Value);
        resultMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Теперь у вас получается «нормальная» функция с нативной сигнатурой, можете её использовать в C++-коде.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать консольное приложение на C#, далее его вызывать из C++ кода, передавая нужные аргументы и читая результаты выполнения программы.

Ну это похоже на костыльное решение.